# Multiple submit buttons from multiple views ASP .NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

I´m working on ASP .NET MVC 5 application and now I´m implementing newsletter functionality. I have master (parent view) with all stuff and on this view there is also box with input field for email and submit button. After click on this button, controller method insert this e-mail to subscribers tab. I´ve got GET/POST method and PartialView for this Newsletter (all newsletter´s code is in separate area).
Everything works fine, there is only one problem. On master page I have another submit button (for submitting search string) so everytime after submitting search string, code also submit newsletter form.
Is there any solution to separate this two submit buttons and way to not refresh whole page after submit newsletter (PartialView) form?

Here is my Newsletter PartialView called **_SignIn**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-12", style="text-align: left; padding-left: 30px;"})
        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsletterType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12", style = "text-align: left; padding-left: 30px;" })
        <br />
        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.NewsletterType, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsletterType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-10" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Prihlásiť" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for any response!

Comment: Check this out http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/cM1X161112-Handling-multiple-submit-buttons-on-the-same-form---MVC-Razor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only achieve this using ajax calls, with that, you do not need to refresh the whole page.

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-12", style="text-align: left; padding-left: 30px;"})
        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", id = "emailTxt"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsletterType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12", style = "text-align: left; padding-left: 30px;" })
        <br />
        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.NewsletterType, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsletterType, "", new { @class = "text-danger", id = "ddlType" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-10" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-newsletter"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
            var model = {
                email: $('.emailTxt').text();
                NewsletterType: $('.ddlType :selected').text();
            }

            $(.btn-newsletter).click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: model,
                beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('__RequestVerificationToken',  $('body').find('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]'));},
                statusCode: {
                    200: function (data) { success(data); },
                    500: function (erro) { error(erro); }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I´m such a new in ASP .NET, how to call and where to put this ajax call? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. Is there some way how to get return value from controller to ajax call? I´ve got multiple checks there in controller and I need to show result of call to user. Thanks

Comment: Yes, in the callback of you ajax call, in the statusCode : {} you have 200, wich means when success, you will hit that when everithing works fine on your controller, and there you get the response.

Answer (score 0):

Add **name** attribute to your buttons, and use the value in your controller to distinguish which button was invoked.

```
    <button type="submit" id="btnSave" name="Command" value="Save">Save</button>
 <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="Command" value="Submit">Submit</button> 

public ActionResult YourAction(Model model, string Command)
{
   if(Command == "Save") {} 
}
```

Refer to [Handling multiple submit buttons](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/cM1X161112-Handling-multiple-submit-buttons-on-the-same-form---MVC-Razor.html) for more info.

*To prevent the full postback (refresh) you could use AJAX*

Answer (score 0):

You have to have two separate forms to handle each submission or handle it through some form of Javascript. I'd suggest using 2 separate forms. Put the search string submission in the parent view since it should be on all the pages and close the form. Then you can render your partial view for the newsletter subscription with a form inside of it.

Basically:

Parent view

```
...
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            ... 
            <!-- Search string input field and submit button -->
            ...
        </div>
    }
    <div>
        @Html.RenderPartial("_SignUp")
    </div>
...
```

_SignUp Partial view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
       ... 
       <!--  Subscriber email input and submit -->
       ...
    </div>
}
```